# GoogleMap in Android not displaying Markers

Tags: android, google-maps-android-api-2

I am making an app for one of my classes, and I need to display markers on a map. Two weird things are happening: first, onMapReady is being executed twice, and second, the markers are not showing up on the map. This is my code:

```
public class MapFragment extends SupportMapFragment implements OnMapReadyCallback {

private GoogleMap mMap;
private Event mEventSelected;
private Person mPersonSelected;
private Map<Marker, Event> mMapMarkers;
private List<Polyline> mLines;
private TextView mPersonFullName;
private TextView mEventDescription;
private LinearLayout mMapEvent;
private ImageView mEventIcon;
private MenuItem searchIcon;
private MenuItem filterIcon;
private MenuItem settingsIcon;
private MenuItem topIcon;
private String EVENT_ID;


@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setHasOptionsMenu(true);
    mMapMarkers = new HashMap<>();
    mLines = new ArrayList<>();
    mEventSelected = null;
    mPersonSelected = null;

    getMapAsync(this);

}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState){

    super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_map, container, false);
    drawDefaultLayout(v);
    return v;
}
private void pinEvents() {
    mMap.clear();
    Map <String, Event> events = FamilyMapData.getEvents();

    for (Event event : events.values())
    {
        LatLng coordinates = new LatLng(event.getLatitude(), event.getLongitude());
        String description = event.getDescription();
        float color = 0;
        switch (description){
            case "baptism":{
                color = BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_CYAN;
                break;
            }
            case "birth":{
                color = BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_BLUE;
                break;
            }
            case "death":{
                color = BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_AZURE;
                break;
            }
            case "marriage":{
                color = BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_RED;
                break;
            }
            case "christening":{
                color = BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_ORANGE;
                break;
            }
            case "census":
            {
                color = BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_GREEN;
                break;
            }
        }


        mMapMarkers.put(mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(coordinates).icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(color))), event);

    }
}
@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
    mMap = googleMap;
    pinEvents();
}
```

I was hoping some of you would be able to help me figure out why the markers are not showing up on the map.

Thank you in advance,

EDIT

This is the xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
          android:orientation="vertical"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="match_parent">


<fragment
    android:id="@+id/map"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
    android:layout_weight="5"/>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:baselineAligned="false"
        android:id="@+id/map_event">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:id="@+id/icon_event_divisor">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:paddingTop="40dp"
                android:paddingBottom="40dp"
                android:paddingStart="20dp"
                android:paddingEnd="20dp"
                android:clickable="false"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:id="@+id/event_icon"/>

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            >

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="@string/person_full_name"
                    android:textSize="30sp"
                    android:id="@id/person_full_name"/>
                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textSize="25sp"
                    android:text="@string/event_description"
                    android:layout_below="@id/person_full_name"
                    android:id="@+id/event_description"/>

            </RelativeLayout>

        </LinearLayout>


    </LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess your onMapReady function is not triggered at all. 
So your pinEvents function is also not triggered.

You have to call getMapAsync() to trigger the onMapReady() Which you have done in onCreate here view is not created still, so do it in onCreateView.

I suggest you to change the name of your class as there is MapFragment and SupportMapFragment related to google maps to avoid confusion.

If you are using support fragment, you need to change the code as following.

```
SupportMapFragment mapFragment =  ((SupportMapFragment)getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager())
                        .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
                    mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
```

Else use this one:

```
MapFragment mapFragment = (MapFragment) getFragmentManager()
                    .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
                mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: thank you for your quick reply.
I tried doing that, but mapFragment is null, so I'm getting a NullPointerException when I call getMapAsync on it.

Comment: Can you post the xml as well?

Comment: Done, I should have put it there before, thank you for reminding me.

Comment: I also tried that, but I don't have access to getSupportFragmentManager since I am extending from SupportMapFragment, so I have tried with both getChildFragmentManager and getFragmentManager, but they return null.

Comment: you can do getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager() find my updated answer.

Comment: unfortunately that is still returning null. Could it be because I'm trying to find the id of the map before I inflate the view?

Comment: Your comment was right, I needed to move it to my onCreateView instead of my onCreate. Thank you so much.

Comment: I voted up, someone else must have voted down. Please notice that my question was also voted down...